Clearing previous cell output on VSCode jupyter notebook
While using the jupyter notebook on VSCode, while running a cell block multiple time, all of the previous outputs are there which was not the case before, i want the previous output to go woosh when i re-run that cell. Can someone help me?
I tried scrolling through the setting but couldn't find the one i needed.
